# How do I cast class method to QScriptEngine::FunctionSignature

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, qtscript

I want to pass this method:

```
QScriptValue ScriptProcessContext::construct(QScriptContext * ctx, QScriptEngine *)
{
    return this->newInstance();
}
```

to [`QScriptEngine::newFunction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#newFunction-2). I tried the following options:

- As in documentation [and also this example code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-script-customclass-bytearrayclass-cpp.html):

  ```
  QScriptValue ctor = engine->newFunction(construct);
  ```

  Error:

  ```
  error C3867: 'ScriptProcessContext::construct': function call missing argument list; use '&ScriptProcessContext::construct' to create a pointer to member
  ```
- Force the cast:

  ```
  QScriptValue ctor = engine->newFunction((QScriptEngine::FunctionSignature)construct);
  ```

  Error:

  ```
  error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'QScriptEngine::FunctionSignature'
  ```
- Cast the pointer to member

  ```
  QScriptValue ctor = engine->newFunction(
     (QScriptValue(ScriptProcessContext::*)(QScriptContext *, QScriptEngine *))
      &ScriptProcessContext::construct
  );
  ```

  Error:

  ```
   error C2664: 'QScriptValue QScriptEngine::newFunction(QScriptEngine::FunctionSignature,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QScriptValue (__cdecl ScriptProcessContext::* )(QScriptContext *,QScriptEngine *)' to 'QScriptEngine::FunctionSignature'
  ```

So how to write it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the original error message suggested?

Comment: @nwp That's what you can see in the last example

Comment: The last example shows an insane C cast of pointers to member function. That's not at all what the error message suggested.

Comment: Also the function you are showing has a different signature than [the expected function signature](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscriptengine.html#FunctionSignature-typedef). Casting a function pointer will not somehow provide the `ScriptProcessContext` required to call the function you want it to call.

Comment: @nwp It's not insane at all and has no effect, the error is the same when one comments it out. Which is unsurprising since I just literally wrote cast to cast it to the function I defined earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to pass a memberfunction. That is not supported. Use a free function or a static method.

Note that in both cases, you won't have a `this` pointer. You need to write the function in a way that it doesn't need an object.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. Just changing it to `static` solved the issue.